# Get JSON Object Keys in a loop with default order android

Tags: android, json, parsing, object

I want to parse `JSONObject` and get its keys in the order they do represent to me when i receive. I don't want use `JSONObject.keys()` as this function giving undefined order of json keys and fully unordered,and this is a huge problem right now because I'm stuck in this position and i have to get `json` object keys.So is there any way to achieve it? Doing researches i never came across to code which can parse json object keys except `JSONObject.keys()` which giving reverse order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to achieve what you want with a `JSONObject` because `JSONObject`s are not ordered by definition and you shouldn't rely on the insertion order. If you need something ordered you should look into `JSONArray`

Comment: you have to use a structure lie [ { "a" : "b" }, { "c" : "d" } ] . So every entry of the JSONArray is a JSONObject that contains only a pair key value, and you have to retrieve the key (with `keys()`) for each JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that although **JSONArray** gives the proper order, the order won't be kept in **HashMap**, if you're using it for saving the values.

Using **LinkedHashMap** solves the order issue.